# Why does WordPress create two transients with the same name when I specify timeout value?

Tags: plugin-development, transient

Working with transients with a timeout, I seem to be getting two transients created, and I don't quite understand why. Looking at the source code on: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_transient/, it would appear this only occurs when wp_using_ext_object_cache() returns false.

My calls are:

```
set_transient( 'mytransientprefix_key', 'value', 3600);
```

and then I update the same transient with:

```
set_transient( 'mytransientprefix_key', 'new_value', 3600);
```

In the wp_options table, I'm then left with:

One **_transient_timeout_mytransientprefix_key** ("value") and **one _transient_mytransientprefix_key** ("new_value").

What?

Comment: The `_timeout_` one ought to a unix timestamp for now + 3600, not 'value'. Is it definitely 'value'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why WordPress creates two transients: Because the first transient with `timeout` in the name, is used for storing the expiration you set for your transient (but the stored value is a UNIX timestamp, not simply the value you passed like `3600`) so that WordPress knows when to delete your transient. As for the second one, it stores the actual transient value that you passed to `set_transient()`, i.e. the second parameter.

```php
$key = 'mytransientprefix_key';

set_transient( $key, 'value', 3600 );
// That will create two options:
// _transient_timeout_mytransientprefix_key and
// _transient_mytransientprefix_key

var_dump(
    get_option( '_transient_timeout_' . $key ),
    get_option( '_transient_' . $key )
);
// Sample output: int(1611143902) string(5) "value"
```

So the value of the "timeout" transient shouldn't be `value` — try the above code and see how it goes?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I somehow overlooked the fact that the table doesn't actually have a timeout column, #LOL (it should, but that's a different discussion).